# Localhost access log shows 500 response but Tomcat log (catalina.out) shows no stack trace

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat

I'm investigating the root cause of some **500 (Internal Server Error)** responses coming from my Java/Spring app.  I can see evidence in `localhost_access_log` of these **500** responses:

```
10.0.2.171 - - [20/Sep/2020:22:21:31 +0000] "POST /item HTTP/1.1" 500 5979
```

But when I look at the corresponding log entries in **catalina.out**, I don't see any stack trace or error.  The logging just sort of stops:

```
2020-09-20 22:21:31.170 [http-nio-8080-exec-248] INFO  c.a.e.w.w.s.c.QueueController - POST REQUEST to /item received
2020-09-20 22:21:31.170 [http-nio-8080-exec-248] INFO  c.a.e.w.w.service.SnsTopicManager - Processing Request. ItemId=304513
```

There should be additional INFO-level logging after this, but clearly something is going wrong, hence the **500** response.  Usually, a **500** response is due to an uncaught exception and there's an accompanying stack trace to explain the issue, but not in this case.

How can an **Internal Server Error** be happening here with no stack trace or other error info being logged?

Comment: There should be catalina.log files.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri there are catalina.out files.  But WITHIN these log files are no log entries which show the cause of the 500 response.

Comment: Try to delete all the log files (if they are not important) and just restart your Tomcat.

Comment: @CFL_Jeff any news? The same thing happens to me :(

Comment: Did you ever get to the root of this?

Comment: @CFL_Jeff same here with tomcat9 - ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're not filtering out the lines of the stack trace by how you're grep'ing/filtering the log.  For example, if you're grep'ing on date, you won't see any logging which doesn't have the date in that line of the log (as is the case with most lines of a stack trace).